# Create promoted links via code

Tags: csom

is just tried (naive) to create a "promoted links" list using code - but neiter OfficePnP:

```
New-PnPList -Title "Top-Links" -Url "topLinks" -Template 170
```

nor CSOM (Powershell) seem to work.

```
$lci = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$lci.Title = "Top-Links"
$lci.TemplateType = 170
$null = $ctx.Web.Lists.Add($lci)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

In both cases I get "invalid template" (actually in german, but that's what it comes to).

Does anyone have a clue on how to provision a promoted links list using (clientside) code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why this is not working, but I created a prompted library by creating a Template.  Create a template for the prompted link library (Library Setting ==> Save as Template).

Try this:

```
$ListTemplateInternalName = "PnpPromotedList.stp" 

$Context = Get-PnPContext
$Web = $Context.Site.RootWeb
$ListTemplates = $Context.Site.GetCustomListTemplates($Web)
$Context.Load($Web)
$Context.Load($ListTemplates)
Execute-PnPQuery

$ListTemplate = $ListTemplates | where { $_.InternalName -eq $ListTemplateInternalName }

if ($ListTemplate -eq $null)
{
    Throw [System.Exception] "Template not found"
}

$ListCreation = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListCreationInformation
$ListCreation.Title = 'Prompted Link List PNP'
$ListCreation.TemplateFeatureId = "192efa95-e50c-475e-87ab-361cede5dd7f"
$ListCreation.TemplateType = 170

$Web.Lists.Add($ListCreation)
Execute-PnPQuery
```

[Reference](https://blog.areflyen.no/2017/04/25/create-list-from-custom-template-in-sharepoint/)

Comment: I was missing the TemplateFeatureId - THX! Using the TemplateType as well as the TemplateFeatureId does the trick!